# Using ISAPI-Rewrite htaccess to 301 redirect multiple urls for multiple hostnames?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, iis, isapi-rewrite, isapi-redirect

I have a single site within IIS, which runs on 4 different hostnames. The CMS handles that, and displays the correct site based on the incoming hostname.

I need to use ISAPI rewrite to handle all the old urls and 301 redirect them to the new equivalants, this is how I currently deal with redirects in my ISAPI-rewrite .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^post/my-old-page-one$ /my-newer-page-one [R=301]
RewriteRule ^post/my-old-page-two$ /my-newer-page-two [R=301]
```

My issue is, I need it to check the domain too for the incoming url. As the sites have the same old urls, which now need to go to a different page.

I was hoping I could so this.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^http://www.siteone.com/post/my-old-page-one$ http://www.siteone.com/my-newer-page-one [R=301]
RewriteRule ^http://www.siteone.com/post/my-old-page-two$ http://www.siteone.com/my-newer-page-two [R=301]

RewriteRule ^http://www.sitetwo.com/post/my-old-page-one$ http://www.sitetwo.com/my-newer-page-one [R=301]
RewriteRule ^http://www.sitetwo.com/post/my-old-page-two$ http://www.sitetwo.com/my-newer-page-two [R=301]
```

But it doesn't work. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use the IIS UrlRewrite plug-in?

Comment: And you saying I can do the above easier using the IIS UrlRewrite plugin? I have in the region of 3000+ urls BTW.

Comment: I don't see the difference between manually defining them with ISAPI or with UrlRewriting...
Btw, have you checked my [Url Tracker Umbraco plug-in](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-url-tracker)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check of the hostname is performed in a separate condition, like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.siteone\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/my-old-page-one$ http://www.siteone.com/my-newer-page-one [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.siteone\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/my-old-page-two$ http://www.siteone.com/my-newer-page-two [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sitetwo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/my-old-page-one$ http://www.sitetwo.com/my-newer-page-one [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sitetwo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/my-old-page-two$ http://www.sitetwo.com/my-newer-page-two [R=301,NC,L]
```